# What is the first equal sums when two independent variables added themselves cumulatively respectively?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

There are two independent integer variables follow uniform distribution:.
$X\sim U(5,15)$ and $Y\sim U(5, 15)$.

$\sum(X)$ and $\sum(Y)$ stand for the sum of variables sampled from $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

I have the following process:

1. Comparing $\sum(X)$ and $\sum(Y)$
2. If $\sum(X)>\sum(Y)$

   sample one more variable $x$ from $X$, calculate the new total number $\sum(X)$.
3. or if $\sum(X)<\sum(Y)$

   sample one more variable $y$ from $Y$, calculate the new total number $\sum(Y)$.
4. repeat step 1~3, until $\sum(X) == \sum(Y)$
5. The first_equal_sum is $\sum(X)$, and **I want calculate the expectation of this first_equal_sum in mathmatics**, and the expectation number of variables needed to sample from $X$ or $Y$

For example:.
for X, we got [ 12, 15], and .
for Y, we got [ 5, 6, 5, 11].

So when the sums equal each other, it is 27, and we took 2 numbers from X and 4 numbers from Y.

I also write code in MatLab, hope it could be illustrated clearly.

```
times = 1e7;    % experiment times

% 1st col is the sum when they equal to each other at the first time
% 2nd and 3rd col are the number of variables when the sums equal
sum_adds = zeros(times, 3); 
for t = 1:times
    sum_var1 = 0;
    sum_var2 = 0;
    num_var1 = 0;
    num_var2 = 0;
    while sum_var1==0 || sum_var1 ~= sum_var2
        if sum_var1 > sum_var2
            sum_var2 = sum_var2 + randi([5, 15]);
            num_var2 = num_var2 + 1;
        else
            sum_var1 = sum_var1 + randi([5, 15]);
            num_var1 = num_var1 + 1;
        end
    end
    sum_adds(t,1) = sum_var1;
    sum_adds(t,2) = num_var1;
    sum_adds(t,3) = num_var2;
end

mu = sum(sum_adds, 1)./times;
fprintf("The expectation of the first equal sum is %.2f\nThe expected number of X is %.2f\nThe expected number of Y is %.2f\n", mu(1), mu(2), mu(3));
```

The result is as follows:

> The expectation of the first equal sum is 100.02.
> The expected number of X is 10.00.
> The expected number of Y is 10.00.

Comment: You might add as clarification (a) your uniform distribution is over integers in $[5,15]$, and (b) you are looking for the expectation of the first common value of the two cumulative sums. What did your simulation suggest?

Comment: @Henry I have revised my explaining, hope it could be more clear